# How to get value of the variable from predefined C++ function using Python?

Tags: python, c++, variant

Is there any way to get value of the variable from predefined C++ function using Python? I have C++ function which takes `variant` type as argument. But we can't define `variant` type variable in python, right? I have tried using `Boost.Python`, `pybind11`. But since I can't edit predefined function, it is not possible to implement them.

Edit:
I have C++ function called `bcap` that takes 2 arguments and returns 2 values.

```
# C++ code    
# Takes these arguments
int32 func_id
variant[] vntArgs
---
# Returns these values
int32 HRESULT
variant vntRet
```

And `variant[] vntArgs` has 2 types of variables.

```
int16 vt
string value
```

And I am trying to call this function using these arguments.

```
#python code
    func_id = 3
    vt = 8
    value_1 = 'value: b-CAP'
    value_2 = 'CaoProv.DENSO.VRC'
    value_3 = 'localhost'
    value_4 = ''
    vntArgs = [vt, value_1, vt, value_2, vt, value_3, vt, value_4]

    response = bcap(func_id, vntArgs)

    #store the response in some variables
    result1 = response.HRESULT
    result2 = response.vntRet
```

Problem is when I run this program, there is this error.

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'vt'
```

What should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What, specifically, is your `variant` type?

Comment: As I added above, it is `int16 and string`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple separate overloads, one for each possible combination of the variant. Would that work?

```
void actual_function(variant<int, double, string> v) {
    // stuff
}

void your_function(int i) {
    actual_function(i); 
}
void your_function(double d) {
    actual_function(d);
}
void your_function(string const& s) {
    actual_function(s); 
}
```

Comment: Does it solve the problem or is it missing any parts?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I have edited original post in order to make it easier to understand. Could you look at this one more time? Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the actual function signature?